# Swift 3 Array contains vs Set contains

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, set

Just wanted to know which one would be faster?
AFAIK `Set` uses `hash` so it should be faster to find an element in Set. But in quite a few projects I've seen the usage of the `array contains` where it could have used `contains` on `Set`.

Comment: Run a few tests and set what results you get.

Comment: As you said, `set` should be faster in ideal scenario.

Answer (score 9):

Given a very quick test, set does look faster for `.contains(` operations.

```
import Foundation

let iterations = 1000000
let array = [ "cat", "dog", "fish", "gerbil", "hamster", "octopus" ]
let set = Set(array)
let bestCase = "cat"
let worstCase = "apple" // Note: Not in the collection.

print("For \(iterations) iterations:")

var start = Date()
for _ in 1...iterations {
    _ = array.contains(worstCase)
}
print("Array took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)s in the worst case")

start = Date()
for _ in 1...iterations {
    _ = set.contains(worstCase) // Note: Not in the collection.
}
print("Set   took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)s in the worst case")

start = Date()
for _ in 1...iterations {
    _ = array.contains(bestCase)
}
print("Array took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)s in the best case")

start = Date()
for _ in 1...iterations {
    _ = set.contains(bestCase)
}

print("Set   took \(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)s in the best case")
```

This outputs:

```
For 1000000 iterations:
Array took 1.67272698879242s in the worst case
Set   took 0.307300984859467s in the worst case
Array took 0.412128031253815s in the best case
Set   took 0.216085016727448s in the best case
```

On a mid-2015 macbook pro using swift 4.0.2. Longer arrays do impact the worst-case scenario. For an array of 24 strings (the same six strings above repeated four times), the array worst-case rose to 5.9s; others stayed broadly the same.

Note:

- This test does not take into account the cost of casting an `Array` to a `Set`.
- I had to bump it up to one million iterations to get a value over a second.
- You lose ordering and the ability to store multiple copies of a value when using `Set` in stead of `Array`.

There are legitimate reasons a developer might use `Array` even though `Set` may be quicker for this one operation.